# Artificial abort in Adaptively-secure Lattice IBE in [ABB10]

Tags: lattice-crypto, identity-based-encryption

I have read the paper [[ABB10]](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/pubs/papers/latticebb.pdf) several times but I still cannot understand thoroughly the "artificial abort" in the security proof of the adaptively-secure IBE in the paper. So my questions are:

1. What is exactly the $\gamma(\cdot)$ function in the **Artificial Abort** step? From what I found in [this paper](https://rist.tech.cornell.edu/papers/wcsec.pdf) (on page 14), it seems that $\gamma(\cdot)$ is the $\alpha(\cdot)$ function in [ABB10]. I do not understand why they define a new function for the same purpose.
2. I have trouble proving the assertion on page 25 in [ABB10] which is $$\epsilon_\max-\epsilon_\min< \alpha_\min|\mathrm{Pr}[W_1]-\frac{1}{2}|$$ where $\epsilon_\min$ and $\epsilon_\max$ are the lower and upper bound of the probability of abort (either by abort check or artificial abort) for all set of queries issued by the adversary; and $\alpha_\min$ is the lower bound for the abort-resistant hash function in the paper.
   I tried to calculate the abort probability, then lower and upper bound it, as follows: $$\mathrm{Pr}[\mathsf{abort}]=\mathrm{Pr}[\mathsf{abortcheck}]+\mathrm{Pr}[\mathsf{artificialabort}]\mathrm{Pr}[\mathsf{abortcheck}]=1-\alpha(\mathbf{I})+\alpha(\mathbf{I})^2$$ where $\mathbf{I}=(\mathsf{id}^*,\mathsf{id}_1,\dots,\mathsf{id}_Q)$ is the set of challenge identity and $Q$ identity-queries from the adversary. Here I assumed that $\gamma$ is $\alpha$ and then I use the lower\upper bound for $\alpha(\mathbf{I})$ to bound this. I think that I did it wrong because the difference is not negligible. But I cannot see where I was wrong and a connection with the quantity $|\mathrm{Pr}[W_1]-1/2|$.

Can you point out the wrongs and give me ideas on how to fix this? Thank you so much.